# How can I force Auth Sign In From Controller

Tags: laravel

Okay, so I know about `middleware` hence the "From Controller" specification in the title but basically, the issue I have is this, I have a SaaS app that I'm adding a gifting feature i.e give someone a plan as a gift and so I need to force login on a regular user while allowing either way on one gifting the plan to make it easier. Makes sense? Anyway, for that reason, I cannot use the `auth` middleware since I have, and want, only 1 checkout page.

So, how can I force login from my `Checkout Controller` like the way the `auth` middleware does it on routes?

Comment: Logout and then use intended url?

Comment: I don't understand, please elaborate. What I'm trying to explain is a page where a user is either forced to login to access it or not depending on parameters instead of a blanket auth protocol. So, let's say you want to buy a plan for someone I don't want to force you to log in to checkout, for convenience's sake, whereas if you're renewing a plan or getting one for yourself then you need to log in so I can record it. Makes sense?

Comment: So you mean if i buy something for stranger i dont need to login, but if i want to buy it for myself then i have to login to do that action?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is: 1. to make it convenient for the ones giving the gift and 2. they are likely not be the intended audience

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't gotten a suggestion, I'll post the workaround I came up with and the potential solution I simply have no time to study up on at present:

Likely solution:
Use `Auth::guard('guard name here')` and you can learn more about this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-authenticating).

My workaround:
I created another route pointing to the same controller function but one is going through `middleware('auth')` while the other isn't. Practical example below.

```
Route::get('checkout/summary', [CheckoutController::class, 'summary'])->middleware('auth')->name('summary');
Route::get('checkout/gift-a-sub', [CheckoutController::class, 'summary'])->name('gift-a-sub');
```

With this, I only require one page to prevent complications while forcing authentication for regular users while those just opting to gift a plan aren't required to do so and all I have to do then is save the data based on a flag created at the Pricing page.